# Fast and accurate approximation to normal_pdf(x) / normal_cdf(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Can anyone suggest a simple and fast approximation to `f(x) = std_normal_pdf(x) / std_normal_cdf(x)`?

Right know I'm approximating the cdf by `1 / (1 + e^(-p(x))`, where p is an optimized odd polynomial, and using `f(x) = -x` for large negative x. This is quite accurate for positive values of `x`, but much less so for moderate negative values.

Perhaps there are better approximations to the tails using asymptotic expansion?

Ideally I want to stick to standard functions.

Comment: Depending on the context of the questions my [answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079559/efficient-and-accurate-computation-of-the-mills-ratio-of-the-standard-normal-dis) on how to compute the Mills ratio of the standard normal distribution accurately might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Φ(z)$is
symmetric about zero, in literature they will only look to approximate all values of $Z>0$.

One very good approximation of the CDF is of Aludaat (2008):

> $$Φ(z) = 0.5+0.5\cdot \sqrt{ 1-exp(-\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{8}} \cdot z^2)}$$

Using neural network structures, you could also get an even more accurate estimate for the tails (and overall):

> $$Φ(z) = 0.5-1.136\tanh(-0.2965z)+2.47\tanh (0.5416z)-3.013\tanh(0.4134z)$$

Comment: The problem is not (just) the accuracy of the cdf approximation, but that for negative x you have 1 small number divided by another, so you lose numerical stability.

Comment: @that's true. Can you tell me the (specific) objective of wanting this approximation?